# Spinner onClick items

Tags: android

i have created a spinner.could i place my spinner items in a table into my java file and call it (maybe from position) in one onClick method?

code:

```
 Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
            ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                    this, R.array.epilogis, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

here i m getting the spinner items from the string.xml..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think this is what you are looking for:

```
array_spinner=new String[5];
array_spinner[0]="1";
array_spinner[1]="2";
array_spinner[2]="3";
array_spinner[3]="4";
array_spinner[4]="5";
Spinner s = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, array_spinner);
s.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: thanks mate..one more,please.in this way,the byDefault-selected item of the spinner appears a radiobox(when the spinner is not pressed).how could i disable it?(i would like to appear only the name of the 1rst spinner item without the radioBox,and when i press it to open the spinner and all the items have radio in order to select them).hope i m understandable

Comment: sure you can. Here's code that sets a different layout resource for dropdown when it's showing list and when it's not:

ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.spinner_item_title, items);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_item);
     spinner.setAdapter(adapter);